# How can I do the same work with one function instead of using two functions in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables

I have two functions which are doing the same work, but function one is calculating with 2 and function two is calculating with 5.

```
private function calcutateNumberTwo() {
    $aArray = array(1,2,3,4);
    $nAnswer = 0;
    foreach ($aArray as $value) {
        $nAnswer = $nAnswer + $value * 2;
    }
    echo $nAnswer;
}

private function calculateNumberVife() {
    $aArray = array(1,2,3,4);
    $nAnswer = 0;
    foreach ($aArray as $value) {
        $nAnswer = $nAnswer + $value * 5;
    }
    echo $nAnswer;
}

public function getFunctions() {
    $this->calcutateNumberTwo();
    $this->calculateNumberVife();
}
```

I want to know how I can use one function which does the same thing by using a variable instead of number 2 and 5.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this will work:

```
private function calculateNumber($mul) {
    $aArray = array(1,2,3,4);
    $nAnswer = 0;
    foreach ($aArray as $value) {
        $nAnswer = $nAnswer + $value * $mul;
    }
    echo $nAnswer;
}

public function getFunctions() {
    $this->calculateNumber(2);
    $this->calculateNumber(5);
}
```

Comment: typo error 2nd function name should be `calcutateNumber`

Comment: @RakeshJakhar thanks for pointing that out, it was a copy/paste from OPs question. I will edit...